# AJAX does not work the second time csrf token issue in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

my ajax call worked at first time but on second time its not work and it return something like ..The action you have requested is not allowed.
in header of console the Status Code is 403 Forbidden

**Controller** method as below..

```
public function authenticate() {
    echo json_encode('sachin');
}
```

**jQuery** function

```
$("#adminFrmSubmitBtn").on('click',function(){
    if($("#admin_login_frm").valid()){
        var frmData=$(this).closest('form').serialize();
        frmData+='&'+$.param({'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'});
        $.ajax({
            url:'<?php echo base_url('login/authenticate12'); ?>',//$(this).closest('form').attr('action'),
            method:$(this).closest('form').attr('method'),
            data:frmData,
            success:function(response){
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    }else{
        return false;
    }
});
```

**Html** Code

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url('login/authenticate'); ?>" method="post" name="admin_login_frm" id="admin_login_frm">               
      <input type="text" name="user_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
      <input type="password" name="user_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" >
</form>
```

Comment: What is your config value of `$config['csrf_regenerate']` ?

Comment: what are you trying to archive with CSRF ??

Comment: [This forum answer suggests passing a new CSRF token back with your json response and updating hidden fields for the CSRF and username for the next ajax call.](https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-61278-post-327081.html#pid327081)

Comment: $config['csrf_regenerate']= true @Hasta Dhana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get fresh CSRF token. we have to get cookie using Javascript because Codeigniter is storing CSRF token in the cookie.

Put below code in your view(.php) file.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function get_cookie(cname) {    //using this function we can get cookie
       var name = cname + "=";
       var ca = document.cookie.split(';'); 
       for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
          var c = ca[i];
          while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
          if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
      }
      return "";   
   }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "YOUR-URL",
        data: {"<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>":csrf_token}, //Add your data which you want to post
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(resp){            
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('Something is wrong');
            window.location.reload();
        }
    }); 

</script>
```